# Maven doesn't include dependency from another project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

Maven isn't copying index.html from another project. I've added dependency for project application. But after the `clean install` the jar file of module2 doesn't have the index.html from application module.

Any suggestion on how to make this work? I've provided the screenshot below.

```
  <dependency>  
    <groupId>sample.multimodule</groupId>  
    <artifactId>sample.multimodule.application</artifactId>  
    <version>1.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>  
  </dependency>
```

I want the index.html to be included in the module2 after compilation.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>sample.multimodule</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample.multimodule</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>sample.multimodule.module2</artifactId>

    <version>1.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>devops</name>
    <description>DevOps Demo Project</description>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <surefire.version>2.17</surefire.version>
        <jacoco.version>0.7.9</jacoco.version>      
    </properties>
    <distributionManagement>
      <repository>
        <id>release</id>
        <name>releases</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/maven</url>
      </repository>
      <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshot</id>
        <name>snapshots</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/maven</url>
      </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
   <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
   <version>1.9.21</version>
</dependency>
        
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>       
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>     <!-- NOT org.junit here -->
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
      <dependency>  
        <groupId>sample.multimodule</groupId>  
        <artifactId>sample.multimodule.application</artifactId>  
        <version>1.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>  
      </dependency>  
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.5.1</version>
              <configuration>
                <tagNameFormat>v@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${surefire.version}</version>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
            <goals><goal>prepare-agent</goal></goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-report</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals><goal>report</goal></goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>           
        </plugins>
    </build>  
</project>
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven-dependency-plugin (unpack-dependencies) ignores configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53557076/maven-dependency-plugin-unpack-dependencies-ignores-configuration)

Comment: no it doesn't. It is not even realted

Comment: If you're trying to extract a resource from a dependency into the current module's target directory, it's very much related.

Comment: I tried that but it still doesn't work. Could you please provide an example on how to make this work?

Comment: First Maven is not doing that because it's not intended to do so. A dependency is in the end a jar file which can contain resources (like the index.html) but by default it's a file which contains class files. The question is: Why do you have the needed `index.html` in one module but need to use it in another module? Why not moving it to the other module where it's needed?